# Set background color of UIVIew fails

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know there have been plenty of variations on this question before, but none seem to capture the particular issue I'm having.  I'm new to iOS development and Objective-C, so please bear with me if this is a particularly basic oversight on my part.

I'm trying to dynamically change the background color of a view (it's a single view application.) I can easily change the background color through statements like:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

or

```
UIColor *newColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:.777777 green:.777777 blue:.777777 alpha:.777777];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:newColor];
```

I run into trouble when I try to change one of those RGBA values dynamically (using sliders, in this case.)  I have four sliders, with tags 0-3, hooked up via this method:

```
- (IBAction)sendColor:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    CGFloat newValue = (CGFloat)(slider.value);
    int senderTag = [sender tag];
    CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(self.view.backgroundColor.CGColor);
    components[senderTag] = newValue;
    UIColor *newColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:components[0] green:components[1] blue:components[2] alpha:components[3]];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:newColor];
    NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f, %f, %f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
    NSLog(@"%@", colorAsString);
}
```

When I move a slider, I can see the values updating properly via NSLog:

*2011-12-13 20:54:26.468 HelloWorld1[1283:707] 0.739568, 0.865854, 1.000000, 1.000000*

...but the background color never changes.  I feel like I'm missing something rudimentary here, do you have any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is that you're writing to a const value, so it's ignoring your new value. Do something like @jojaba suggests below.

Comment: It took me a moment, but I see what you mean.  Thank you!  I will take a look at jojaba's suggestion below.

Comment: just make sure you see my comment there... what jojaba suggests is the right idea but won't actually compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `CGColorGetComponents`. Rather, create a `CGFloat components[4]` ivar in your class and set this directly in the `init`.

Example...

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
    CGFloat components[4];
}
@end
```

...

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil)
    { 
        components[0] = 1;
        components[1] = 1;
        components[2] = 1;
        components[3] = 1;

        self.view.backgrounColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:components[0] green:components[1] blue:components[2] alpha:components[3]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then change only the component that you need to.

```
- (IBAction)sendColor:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    CGFloat newValue = (CGFloat)(slider.value);
    int senderTag = [sender tag];
    components[senderTag] = newValue;
    UIColor *newColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:components[0] green:components[1] blue:components[2] alpha:components[3]];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:newColor];
    NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f, %f, %f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
    NSLog(@"%@", colorAsString);
}
```

Comment: you need to send the address of those components, just the subscript isn't enough for `initWithRed:green:blue:alpha`. So either: `initWithRed:&components[0]...` or `initWithRed:components+0...`

Comment: The code will work. As long as the `components` variable is defined as `CGFloat components[4]`, the values can be access directly as `components[0-3]`.

Comment: Thanks - it's clear I didn't understand how to use CGFloat properly when I started this.  Thank you all for your input!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea why I read this as the get method for the color... I guess because the OP was doing a get first. I even wrote init... in my comment, which obviously doesn't require pointers. Just ignore my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try redrawing the view right after you set the background color, adding this line:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Bear in mind that this method causes the whole view to be redrawn, so putting it on a slider change event may cause overhead.

EDIT:

As pointed out by other answers, however, the main problem here must be that the function `CGColorGetComponents()` indeed returns a constant type.